# Are python's file write() and urlopen() methods asynchronous?

Tags: python, file-io, urllib

As asked in the title, are `open('...','w').write('...')` and `urllib.urlopen('..')` asynchronous calls?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. If you need them to be asynchronous then consider looking at event frameworks such as Twisted, glib, or Qt.